# k nearest neighbors dictionary for vectors?

Tags: vector, data-structures, data-management

Does there exists a data structure with these properties

1. Stores vectors in a dictionary
2. When given a key that is also a vector, returns the k nearest vectors using a similarity metric (e.g. Euclidean, Cosine)?

Something computationally efficient would be ideal.

Answer (score 5):

What you're describing is also a critical step in the k-nearest-neighbours method. So no need to reinvent the wheel, we can just look how other people have sped up that algorithm.

I don't know about any dictionary like structure that returns this directly, but you could use a k-d tree. If properly implemented, you can get the k closest vectors pretty quickly.

This  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688977/how-do-i-traverse-a-kdtree-to-find-k-nearest-neighbors) might also be interesting.

Comment: do you think this would suffice for 2000 vectors of 512 dimensions?

Comment: yeah, probably, you could also search for libraries that implement k-nearest-neighbours for extra speed.

Comment: 512 dimensions seems too large for a kd-tree. After all, you would have 2^512 possible orthants to organize 2000 data points.

Comment: Hmmm, that is true. I was focused on the 2000, not the dimension. I still think some space dividing structure will work, but a kd-tree is indeed not ideal

Comment: It is simply a dictionary whose values are lists (vectors).